# How to float a <label> to the left of an <input>?

Tags: css, forms, css-float

Consider the following HTML/CSS:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.field {
  overflow: auto;
}
  
.field label {
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
}

.field input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="field">
  <label>Test</label>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

On both Firefox and Chromium, the result ends up looking like this:

[image: label above text input]

Instead, I would like the `<input>` to appear on the same line as the `<label>`. In other words, something like this:

[image: label beside text input]

Why isn't `float: left;` causing the label to appear to the left of the input?

Comment: You set the width of `<input>` to 100%, so it needs a whole line of space, which could make a line break. It'd be better to set all things up by using `display: flex`, which would make your input element flexible in layout.

Answer (score 5):

By making the width of the text input 100% and a block, the text box takes the entire width of the line thus pushing the textbox onto the second line. There are many methods of doing what you are attempting. One method - if you change the text input to a fixed width (pixel or smaller than 100%), you should get the desired results.

```
.field label {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
}
.field input {
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I saw you responded to another answer where you intended to keep the 100% width on the input. You can accomplish this and not arbitrarily select a fixed width by using the table/table-cell css classes. The field must be full width and defined as a table. The float must be removed, then the label/input be table-cells.

```
.field {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.field > label,
.field > input {
    display: table-cell;
}

.field > input {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1rhtgzf0/1/

Comment: Would still need to remove `display: block;` declaration as well.

Comment: Yes, best practice. And I'm aware it works for that. The best thing to do would be to add `.field > * { display: inline-block; }` and set the width for `.field input` to auto. (i.e., `width: auto;`). That's the better solution.

Comment: However, @ChrisYongchu, it would seem that solution would be visually the same as if no styles at all were applied. The OP seemingly intends to have the textbox much wider than the default width of textbox, so that doesn't solve anything for the OP. The display is fine (inline-block vs inline as default - can't really debate too much in this context except that block and floats are not ideal here) - it's just the widths that are in question here of the input.

Comment: Sorry, I must had misread the question about `Why isn't float: left; causing the label to appear to the left of the input?` and `I would like the <input> to appear on the same line as the <label>.` My apologies sir.

Answer (score 1):

Took a note from Bootstrap (http://www.getbootstrap.com):

```css
.field {
    border-collapse: separate;
    display: table;
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
}

label {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 1%;
}
input {
    display: table-cell;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="field">
  <label>Test</label>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: After removing all of the unnecessary styles, it appears that I need to add `display: table;` to `.field` and `display: table-cell;` to the `label` and `input`.

Comment: Those are the key elements that make this possible. Play around with the example and get it to flow with you styles.

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to leave some space to your layout...

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.field {
  overflow: auto;
}

.field label {
  float: left;
  width: 10%;
}

.field input {
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close. Remember that a label and input are two separate boxes. You  set width in `.field input` to 100%. By setting the width of the input textbox to 100%, you're taking up 100% of that space that the label and textbox would share. This results in forcing the input textbox to be beneath the label. By setting  `float:left;` to input and removing 100% from `.field input`, it'll work.

Here's the solution I came up with.

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.field {
  overflow: auto;
}

.field label {
  float: left;
  text-align:right;
  width: 80px;
}

.field input{
  float:left;
}

<div class="field">
   <label>Test</label>
   <input type="text">
</div>`
```

Comment: But then the `<input>` doesn't occupy the entire width of its parent.

Comment: @Nathan my mistake. I misinterpreted your question since it wasn't stated that you wanted input to remain 100%.